# Remove a 4-way switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, multiway-switch, usa

I have 3 switches on the same circuit that power lights in my family room and garage.  Two 3-ways are located at each end of my family room and the 4-way is in my garage.  I want to remove the garage 4-way switch (Switch B in diagram) and the cable that powers garage lights (Cable 3 in diagram).  Those I intend to hook into an outlet nearby for power.  I am unsure how to connect the wires at the 4-way once it is removed so the 2 3-ways in the circuit will still function as a normal 3-way.[image: Circuit Diagram]

Comment: A few things don't quite add up. Blue = white - I get that, so it means you have black/white and black/red/white - traditional cable wire colors. But what is with the green in 6/C - is that actually red? Where do the cables go/what's connected? It looks like 1 = incoming power, 3 to the lights (presumably garage **and** family room), not clear about 2, 4, 5, 6 - some of those should be connected or it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Photos might help, just to prove that this really has been transcribed correctly. I strongly suspect it hasn't been. "I roll to disbelieve...."

Comment: Does it come any closer to making sense if 4=6,  2=5,  green=red, and A got wired backwards at some point? That's the best I can do toward guessing how the switch loop at C was intended to work, and I'm still not convinced.

Comment: There's no way to tell (without a meter) how switch B is connected.

Comment: Which color wires are hooked to which color screws on switch B?

Comment: It's a shame how chimpanzees are abused by thoughtless humans. Kidnapped from their forest home, made objects of ridicule in circus shows, injected with noxious humours in horrible laboratories, forced to install home  wiring...